# How can I add a custom IP limit to my vpn server?

Tags: networking, ip, vps

How can I add a custom IP limit to my v2ray VPN server configs so that only 1 or 2 users can get connected?

Comment: Perhaps with a subnet mask at the router? E.G. 255.255.255.252 would limit it to 2 connections. See https://serverfault.com/questions/87216/can-i-use-a-subnet-mask-to-limit-the-number-of-users-on-a-router However, a user could intentionally duplicate an IP address.

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried?